# A better word than Lessor?

Tags: word-choice

I just learned the word *Lessor*.

Is this a common word? Is there a better choice for less proficient English speakers which has the same meaning?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.se. Did you check a dictionary/thesaurus? Questions which do not mention own research are not encouraged here. BTW, some words which may help you are _letter_ (alternative meaning), renter and in the case of real estate, landlord/landlady.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of Thesaurus.com, for example, but it provides plenty of options with no advice. I wanted to hear what people had to say about which word is most commonly used.

Comment: DAE: you do need to check a dictionary, which will usually tell you if a word exists and will also explain it, and maybe even provide synonyms. We have a [comprehensive list of references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) in Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lessor%2C+landlord&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clessor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clandlord%3B%2Cc0), landlord is more common, it's actually mentioned in the dictionary definition of lessor ([ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lessor)).

> *lessor* A person who leases or lets a property to another; a landlord: